# django & postgresql - could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

I have an os x server running django 1.6 and postgresql 9.

I have just noticed that if I logout of the machine I can no longer connect to my app from another machine.

The error is:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have had a look around for a solution but I can't seem to get it to work.

My django settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypw',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

And as I say if I log in to the server with my server user i can then immediately access my web app from another machine. I hope that makes sense. It's as if postgresql runs when my user logs in.

I am assuming that postgresql runs as root / in the background despite whatever user is logged in.

Any ideas?

Comment: if those error messages are for the "other" machine, then why is it trying to connect to 127.0.0.1? That's the TCP loopback address and ALL machines have that so they can talk to themselves. your "other" box is trying to connect to a pg running on the same other box, not your server.

Comment: can you login with [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/)?

Comment: Marc and Ricky thanks for writing back. Sorry i should explain a little better. The server (mac A) is running django and using its own postgresql db. I can visit it's web app from another machine - obviously through a browser. Now if the server restarts and is then left at the mac os x login screen I can not get to the web app from the other machine. I need to log in to the mac server's admin user account for the web app to then be reachable. The above error is what i can see from the 2nd machine's browser.

Comment: If you are hung at that login screen, is there actually a running instance of the database server to connect to?

Comment: hi souldex, yes that's what i am wondering, does th postgresql server run once the machine has booted or do i need to login as an admin user for it to run?